# How to get the top row for each studid?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Is it possible to get the following result?

Note: 'S' for summer class.

```
|    sy   |sem|  studid |studmajor|
|2013-2014| 2 |2012-5037| COM SCI |
|2013-2014| 1 |2012-5037| COM SCI |
|2012-2013| 2 |2012-5037|   ENGG  |
|2012-2013| 1 |2012-5037|   BA    |
|2011-2012| S |2010-2011|   IT    |
|2011-2012| 2 |2010-2011|   IT    |
|2011-2012| 1 |2010-2011|   IT    |
|2010-2011| 2 |2010-2011|   IT    |
|2010-2011| 1 |2010-2011| PUP/CBP |
```

to

```
|    sy   |sem|  studid |studmajor|
|2013-2014| 2 |2012-5037| COM SCI |
|2011-2012| S |2010-2011|   IT    |
```

if can't, maybe the one below?

```
|    sy   |sem|  studid |studmajor|
|2013-2014| 2 |2012-5037| COM SCI |
|2013-2014| 1 |2012-5037| COM SCI |
|2011-2012| S |2010-2011|   IT    |
|2011-2012| 2 |2010-2011|   IT    |
|2011-2012| 1 |2010-2011|   IT    |
|2010-2011| 2 |2010-2011|   IT    |
```

I don't want to see the previous major he/she attended, I only want to see his/her current one.

This is my query so far:

```
select studmajor,sy,sem,studid from semester_student ORDER BY sy DESC,sem DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DISTINCT ON`  with the right `ORDER BY` defining which row to choose from each set:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ON (studid) *
FROM   semester_student
ORDER  BY studid DESC, sy DESC, sem DESC;
```

See:

- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)